# Magnetic field inside a cylinder

Tags: electromagnetism

> A magnetically “hard” material is in the shape of a right circular cylinder of length $L$ and radius $a$. The
> cylinder has a permanent magnetization $M_{0}$, uniform through-out its volume and parallel to its axis

While doing this problem, I notice that I am not really sure when I can use some formulas given by electromagnetic books. So I have decided to question it here:

Why can't I say that $$\vec M = \chi \vec H,$$ and so $$\vec B = \mu \vec H = \mu \vec M /\chi $$??

That is, when are this equations valid to be used? I know that the right approach here consists in analyzing the field generated by the current $\vec K = \vec M \times \vec n$ at the surface, my question is specifically on how/when can i use the two expression above.

Answer (score 1):

These formulae are applicable for linear materials only. Such materials are, by definition, those for which such conditions (and the similar ones for the electric field) hold. In general, one has only
$$\vec{H} = \frac{1}{\mu_0}\vec{B} - \vec{M}.$$

In short, the formulae you gave can be used when the material can be assumed to be linear.

Comment: For more details, see the [Wikipedia page on constitutive equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutive_equation#Electromagnetism).

Answer (score 0):

The expression $\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}$ for the magnetic properties of soft magnetic materials is a simple and crude approximation although it is very useful.
When this equation holds, $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{H}$ are parallel and point in the same direction; this is not always true. On the other hand, inside a  magnet, $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{H}$ are roughly anti-parallel, i.e., facing opposite directions. This means at the working point (shown green circle) in BH curve, B is positive while H negative. Inside magnet, $\vec{B}=\mu\vec{H}$ does not hold.[image]